# Using wordpress the_content filter to inject javascript yields javascript syntax error

Tags: javascript, wordpress, filter

I'm writing a wordpress plugin to inject some javascript and html into a post. Using the "the_content" filter I manage to insert my  tag with all my javascript functions and all of my html markup afterwards. The problem is the scripts dont work and firebug labels it a syntax error without being very precise as to where the error lies.

Here is the content of the javascript tags that gets inserted into the page which doesn't seem to hold any kind of syntax error when I check it.

```
    <![CDATA[ 
    Votes = {};
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(".starContainer span").hover(sr_addBG("http://revealcoupons.com/wp-content/plugins/StarRatingLite/images/stars.png"), sr_removeBG());
    });
function sr_addBG(ImgURL){
    $(this).css("background","transparent url("+ImgURL+") repeat-x 0 -60px");
}
function sr_removeBG(){
    $(this).css("background","none");
}
function sr_castVote(ID,Vote, ImgURL){
    Votes[ID] = Vote;
    $("#starContainer"+ID+" span").css("background","none");
    $("ID"+ID+"Star"+Vote).css("background","transparent url("+ImgURL+") repeat-x 0 -60px");
}
function sr_verifyVote(NbFeatures){
    var count = 0;
    for (var e in Votes)
    {count++;}
    return count >= NbFeatures;
} 
function sr_submitVotes(NbFeatures, PostID){
    if (sr_verifyVote(NbFeatures))
    {
        ajaxReq = new XMLHttpRequest();ajaxReq.onreadystatechange=function() 
        {
            if (ajaxReq.readyState == 4 && ajaxReq.status == 200)
            {
                alert("BAM! vote submitted. Thank you");
            }
        }
        var voteStr = "";
        for (var vote in Votes)
        {voteStr += vote+"[eq]"+Votes[vote]+"[amp]";}
        voteStr = voteStr.substring(0, voteStr.length - 5);
        ajaxReq.open("http://revealcoupons.com/wp-content/plugins/StarRatingLite/StarRatingLite.php?PostID="+PostID+"&votes="+voteStr");
        ajaxReq.send();
    }
    else
    { 
        alert("You must vote on all features before submitting your opinion.");
    }
}]]&gt;
```

The only error that firebug yields is "syntax error" without being more specific. The only thing I haven't written per so is the end of the cdata section where the ">" character got automatically replaced by ">".

Thanks for any input!

Comment: can you paste the firebug error output?

Comment: the firebug output is actually that whole javascript without newlines and tabs as I remove them with preg_replace. I reformatted it for lisibility

Answer (score 0):

your `.hover()` is wrong. it is expecting 2 function handlers, and instead you are passing `undefined` twice

try with this, were i added function wrappers

```
$(".starContainer span").hover(function(){sr_addBG("http://revealcoupons.com/wp-content/plugins/StarRatingLite/images/stars.png")}, function(){sr_removeBG()});
```

Comment: I've added the anonymous function wrappers but it still yields the same error (syntax error). Any more insights as to the possible source of this error?

Comment: have you tried removing the opening and closing of the CDATA section? or commenting it